# Error inserting new pass entry into PassGroupRenderableMap

Tags: c++, ogre, terrain-rendering

I started playing around with terrain and I am getting this assertion in

`QueuedRenderableCollection::addRenderable: "Error inserting new pass entry into PassGroupRenderableMap"`

I am trying to find out what I have done wrong, but it is hard, so perhaps someone has any idea of what may it be.

I can reproduce it easily on my engine and my scene consists only of:

- 1 terrain page
- 1 mesh (highlander house)
- 1 directional light

If I reload the scene and look again at the house the assertion fires and it is very strange. I have tried to debug the code and the only reason for the assertion to fire that I have found is the hash being changed after the node was inserted on the map.

Any ideas how can I find a solution to it? Which data and information I can provide to help debug this?

Also I have seen in the forum some posts about this assertion, but no one that I have seen explain ways to debug or to fix it.

Ogre version 1.7.1
Windows 7
render Direct3d 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a bug report](http://www.ogre3d.org/mantis/view.php?id=130) with a workaround, probably the same issue?

It was discussed [here in the Ogre Forum](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=189032#189032).

Comment: Looks like I need to use the workaround, do you know how to correctly implement it?

Comment: @bcsanches No, I dont use Ogre, but I would start with the one in the bug report. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I am using it, just added it to the main lopp right before rendering a frame, so far it is working.